# How do I split two or more inner joins into multiple select statements

Tags: sql

```
SELECT e.cempnoee, e.cempname, e.cempemail, s.csrvposition, s.csrvbranch, s.csrvcostcentr, b.cbrndesc, p.caddnophoneh FROM emas e 
        inner join esrvc s on e.cempnoee = s.csrvnoee 
        inner join cbranch b on s.csrvbranch = b.cbrncode
        inner join eaddrs p on e.cempnoee = p.caddnoee
```

The SQL dialect I am using (Lianja/VFP) does not support multiple inner join statements as of the time of writing.  How do I split the above SQL statement into multiple select statements as a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After corresponding with the author of Lianja, spliting the SQL statement works:

```
SELECT emas.cempnoee, emas.cempname, emas.cempemail, esrvc.csrvposition, esrvc.csrvbranch, esrvc.csrvcostcentr FROM emas inner join esrvc on emas.cempnoee = esrvc.csrvnoee into cursor esc
SELECT *, cbranch.cbrndesc FROM esc inner join cbranch on esc.csrvbranch = cbranch.cbrncode into cursor esbc
SELECT *, eaddrs.caddnophoneh FROM esbc inner join eaddrs on esbc.cempnoee = eaddrs.caddnoee
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

You could bring in all the relevant tables locally and then handle the join yourself, but that would first of all be crap, inefficient, and something that you absolutely should not do...

If your SQL database doesn't support multiple joins (and I would find that REMARKABLE), you need to find yourself another database - seriously. Don't cause yourself years of pain for the sake of a bad decision now...

Answer (score 0):

Actually Lianja does support multiple joins, it's just a bit weird syntax

Try something like this, and it should work

```
SELECT emas.cempnoee, emas.cempname,;
       emas.cempemail, esrvc.csrvposition,;
       esrvc.csrvbranch, esrvc.csrvcostcentr,;
       cbranch.cbrndesc, eaddrs.caddnophoneh;
FROM emas INNER JOIN esrvc ON emas.cempnoee = esrvc.csrvnoee,;
esrvc INNER JOIN cbranch ON esrvc.csrvbranch = cbranch.cbrncode,;
emas INNER JOIN eaddrs ON emas.cempnoee = eaddrs.caddnoee
```

[Lianja SQL_SELECT](http://www.lianja.com/doc/index.php/SQL_SELECT) and [Lianja docs](http://www.lianja.com/doc/index.php/Using_Lianja_SQL)

Comment: I tried this syntax but it didn't give me the correct result.  Guess this is something that Lianja needs to work upon.

Comment: @dandyling thats very strange, as in the docs they show an example of *multiple joins*. Yes, maybe they have to work on it :p

Answer (score 0):

Lianja now (since at least Feb 2017, Version 3.2) handle joins in the way handled by VFP, SQL Server, etc.